# Format numbers (amount) according to computer setup in C#

Tags: c#

In C# im trying to format an amount according to the setup on the computer.

So for instance if the setup on en-US are xxxx.xx (separated by an dot) and in nb-NO it is xxxx.xx (separated by an comma) I want to auto-detect that and format the amount accordingly.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Yep, that's correct :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [double.TryParse in dutch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905754/double-tryparse-in-dutch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
double amount = xxxx.xx;
string formattedCurrency=amount.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: Hi. 
Im getting this error:

Document.LoadScript:: c:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Temp\CSSCRIPT\tmp56.tmp(17,20): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'double'

c:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Temp\CSSCRIPT\tmp56.tmp(24,20): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'double'

c:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Temp\CSSCRIPT\tmp56.tmp(30,20): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'double'

Comment: i guess you are using something like this double amount = "1234.56",in that case dont use double datatype,use string

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to get the value formatted as a currency (as a string), you can do this:

```
MyDecimal.ToString("c");
```

If you're looking for certain properties, you can look in a particular culture's [`NumberFormat` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.numberformat.aspx), which is of type [`NumberFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx).

This class contains properties which tell you the culture's thousands separator, decimal separator, currency symbol, how to handle negative numbers etc.

Useful properties for currencies:

- [`CurrencyDecimalSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencydecimalseparator.aspx)
- [`CurrencySymbol`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencysymbol.aspx)
- [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Two Interface  IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter,to Create you Format:
 public class TestConvertor: IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
    {
        public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
        {
            if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
                return this;
            return null;
        }

```
    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        decimal amount = arg is decimal ? (decimal) arg : 0;
        return amount.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double amount = 2541.25;
        var f = string.Format(new TestConvertor(), "{0:Currency}", 2545);
        Console.WriteLine(f);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```